# Is there an "Identity" filter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that takes in some complex parameters and is expected to return a filter to be used on a pandas dataframe.

```
filters = build_filters(df, ...)
filtered_df = df[filters]
```

For example, if the dataframe has series `Gender` and `Age`, `build_filters` could return `(df.Gender == 'M') & (df.Age == 100)`

If, however, `build_filters` determines that there should be no filters applied, is there anything that I can return (i.e. the "identity filter") that will result in `df` not being filtered?

I've tried the obvious things like `None`, `True`, and even a generator that returns `True` for every call to `next()`

The closest I've come is

```
operator.ne(df.ix[:,0], nan)
```

which I think is silly, and likely going to cause bugs I can't yet forsee.

Comment: Hard to tell if we don't see how you defined `build_filters`

Answer (score 1):

You can return `slice(None)`. Here's a trivial demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]])

df2 = df[slice(None)]  # equivalent to df2 = df[:]
df2[0] = -1

assert df.equals(df2)
```

Alternatively, use [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) and return `df` if no filters need to be applied:

```
def apply_filters(df):
    # some logic
    if not filter_flag:
        return df
    else:
        # mask = ....
        return df[mask]

filtered_df = df.pipe(apply_filters)
```